# Get my Nth tweet via twitter API

Tags: twitter

Looking at the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid), I'm struggling to see how I could get my `N`th tweet. I know there is a maximum number we can go back (something like 3200 latest tweets or so), but I'd like to access a specific tweet that I know the `N` of (i.e. it was my `789th` tweet (note that it really wasn't that specific N)).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The tweet doesn't contain information on its number in stream.
All you can do is count back: you know your current tweet number (`statuses_count`) and just count backwards in `statuses/user_timeline` (not too hard with pagination, but they re going to disable it soon).